# checkout master

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, git

Hola estoy subiendo archivos mediante git sin embargo cuando quiero entrar a la rama master con git checkout master este me genera el siguiente error:

error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

cual podría ser la causa?

Comment: Podrías colocar el comando que estás ejecutando en la pregunta?

Comment: En todo caso, estás pidiendo (según tu explicación) hacer checkout de master. Ese error indica normalmente que la rama master no existe en local. Lo que git hace en ese caso es verificar si hay un remoto _y solo un remoto_ que tenga configurada esa rama. Si existe un solo remoto configurado con esa rama, la crea en el local a partir de esa rama remota y le hache checkout. Si no existe en un remoto o si hay más de un remoto con esa rama, creo que te sale ese error. Así que, resumen: git no sabe a qué rama te estás refiriendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la rama master no existe, puedes revisar las ramas que tienes usando **git branch** -v o simplemente **git branch**.

Es probable que la rama principal ahora sea main, sin embargo revisa con git branch para comprobar cual es.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió